# Get Partial View by Ajax Call and Display Modal Single Value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I know I am missing something very basic. I have a HomeController and inside that there is a partial view. There is a button inside partial view which gets data(ParserModel) via ajax call. Now the single data value is not getting in _Parser.cshtml.
Here is my HomeController ajax method which calls ParserView data.

```
 public IActionResult Parser()
    {
        
        ParserModel parser = new ParserModel();
        parser.LogoPosition = "This is correct";
        return PartialView("_Parser");
        
    }
```

Below is my _Parser.cshtml view which is not setting the value of LogoPosition

```html
@using PageRefine.Models
@model PageRefine.Models.ParserModel
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Parser" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#CustomerList">
<button type="submit" id="button1">Click</button>  

 <p>@Model.LogoPosition</p>@*This is giving null reference error. Here it should be "This is correct"*@
 <p>@Html.RenderPartial("_Parser", Model.LogoPosition)</p>@*This is printing LogoPosition*@
 </form>
```

Here is Index.cshtml code for partial view

```html
<div id="CustomerList">
                            <partial name="_Parser" />
                        </div>
```

What should I do to get the modal values by their name in Partial View (_Parser.cshtml). Let me know if I am missing any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model to your partial view

```
 public IActionResult Parser()
    {
        
        ParserModel parserModel = new ParserModel();
        parserModel.LogoPosition = "This is correct";
        return PartialView("_Parser", parserModel);
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was know something very basic is missing.

Comment: Just a additional query here. When I load the partial view in Index.chtml first time then Model.LogoPosition is NULL as the ajax call is not fired yet. But when I call the ajax call then Model.LogoPosition gets its value. Is there any way I can write so that Model.LogoPosition in partial view only visible when ajax call is fired and not at the first time load.

Comment: You could set a class or style on the paragraph <p class="d-none">@Html.RenderPartial... so that it is hidden and after you do your ajax call you can show it. $("p").removeClass("d-none");